# Datepicker is not allowing the insert in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datepicker, formtastic

I have a tournament model with a field end_date with is a datatime and I am using formtastic for the form like this

```
<%= semantic_form_for @tournament do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :end_date %>
```

this works well and the params come in like this and all saves well

```
"end_date(1i)"=>"2007", "end_date(2i)"=>"4", "end_date(3i)"=>"2", "end_date(4i)"=>"04", "end_date(5i)"=>"07",
```

But i need a datepicker so I have this approach

```
<%= f.input :end_date, :as => :string, :input_html => {:class => "datapicker"}, :hint => "Tournament End Date" %>
```

and the JS

```
 $('#tournament_end_date').datepicker();
```

the datepicker pulls up and all is good but the end_date is not saving....

here are the params

```
 "end_date"=>"10/11/2011",
```

what do i need to do to get this to save ..any ideas

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try adding attr_accessible :end_date to the model code?  <strike>Also check this thread for acceptable input formats for date fields [Rails date format in form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443094/rails-date-format-in-form-field).</strike>  Ignore what's striked out, it's not really relevant.

Comment: its there already...maybe there is something with the format of whats its expecting "end_date(1i)"=>"2007", "end_date(2i)"=>"4", "end_date(3i)"=>"2", "end_date(4i)"=>"04", "end_date(5i)"=>"07",

Comment: trying something...i may have it

Comment: I added     $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat = 'dd M yy';
to the jquery and for some reason it works now...not sure why

Comment: What format does the datepicker inject into the textfield now compared to before?