# Rails 4 populate date_field from db on edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, ruby-on-rails-4, datefield

There are a ton of questions about this but none seem to address my issue. Can't seem to get a date_field to populate correctly from the db on edit. I think one issue might lie in the fact that my db is serialized and date is being stored as a string.

I tried modifying en.yml and localizing the information like in this question: [Rails date format in form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443094/rails-date-format-in-form-field)

```
#en.yml
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%d/%m/%Y"
```

then in my view

```
#edit.html.erb
<%= person.label :dob, "Date of Birth" %>
<%= person.date_field :dob, as: :date, value: l(@request.person[:dob].to_date, format: :default), required: true %>
```

From the console I can say `Request.first.person[:dob].to_date` to get a date object like `Wed, 05 Mar 1986`but it still won't populate the field.

Any guidance would be apprciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get the formatter to work you need to pass it a valid Date object. You mentioned that dates are stored as strings in your database and a string is what the formatter gets as input.

One way to handle that is override the attribute reader in your model or add another method returning the value as an instance of Date.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def date_field
    read_attribute(:date_field).to_s.to_date
  end    
end
```

Comment: So the date_field is (read: should be) receiving a valid date object by my use of `value: l(@request.person[:dob].to_date`

Comment: Right, I haven't read your question carefully enough, sorry. Have you tried to stop on a breakpoint before the `date_field` line to see what the actual `@request.person[:dob]` object looks like?

Comment: Yeah it comes back as a string in "Y%-m%-d%" order. When hitting it with .to_date it comes back as `Wed, 05 Mar 1986` as a date object.